# Allocating memory and assigning it to pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the difference if I do

```
  int *i = new int;
  *i = 5;
  *(i+1) = 20;
```

and

```
  int *i2 = new int [2];
  i2[0] = 5;
  i2[1] = 20;
```

I can access and use these 2 pointers the same way but what is the difference between these 2 examples and what errors can occur if I don't allocate enough memory, as in the first example?

Comment: Errors? What do you mean errors? This is C++. We don't need to stinkin' errors. We order pizza and launch nukes when things go wrong.

Comment: Here the first one may invoke undefined behaviour and most probably will give a segmentation fault error. The second one will work fine. By the way it should be i2[1].

Comment: Run valgrind to see which one of these programs is correct.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes:  You forgot Coke,  Real Programmers drink Coke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the first one invokes **undefined behaviour**.  Anything could happen, including a program crash, or data corruption, or even simply just "working".

Comment: Since I have only allocated memory for 1 int in the first example, why is it possible to do *i(i+1)=20, if enough memory isn't allocated?

Comment: You didn't allocate the memory, but that doesn't mean the memory address doesn't exist. You may be writing in memory that was allocated for something else or possibly not allocated at all.

Answer (score 2):

The first option writes to memory that hasn't been allocated. This could lead to unpredictable behaviour such as a crash.

Comment: This **does** lead to unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: That depends upon your knowledge of the system.  Just because something is undefined as far as the standard is concerned, doesn't mean someone with enough knowledge about the compiler and the target system can't predict what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

In first case we have allocated memory for one integer. so we cannot do *(i+1) which will move to next location which have undefined behaviour i.e., it may crash immediatetly or later.

In later case we are allocating memory for two integers.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable thing is the data corruption, but generally it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in what elements you are accessing.  The syntax `*(i+1)` (pointer notation) and `i[1]` (array element access notation) are the same.  In this case you can think of a pointer and an array as equivalent (hence the two ways of accessing the same element)

As the others have mentioned, you will have undefined behavior if you (try to) access memory that has not been allocated properly.